# Properly using bindCallback with RXJS6 and DWR

Tags: typescript, callback, rxjs, dwr

I'm currently using `bindCallback` the following (now deprecated) way:

```
const someMapping = (data) => { return { ... }};

public someCall(id) {
  // Foo.someFunction is function with callbacks
  return this.toObservable(Foo.someFunction, someMapping, id);
}

private toObservable(func, mappingFunction, ...args: any[]) {
  return bindCallback(func, mappingFunction)(...args);
}
```

Other than this being deprecated, I have another issue. If I call the `someFunction` manually:

```
var callFn = function(data) {...}
var warnFn = function(data) {...}
var errFn = function(data) {...}
Foo.someFunction(id, {callback: callFn, warningHandler: warnFn, errorHandler: errFn})
```

It will throw success, warnings and errors correctly. I didn't create this [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr2/introduction/scripting-dwr.html) callback function (there are many of them), and I can't change them. [Documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback) isn't helping enough.

How can I modify this to handle all three (success, warning, error) callbacks and return as observables? Warning and error can both throw an error.

Comment: What's the signature of `someFunction`? And what's your question?

Comment: It's actually DWR function. `Foo.someFunction = function (p0, p1, p2, _48) { ... };` where p0-p2 are parameters and _48 is callback, got around 150 functions like this. And this callback can somehow return one or three callbacks as in example above.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to know. Your question does not contain an actual question.

Comment: Added some information if it makes more sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to create your own observable.

```
public someCall(id) {
  return new Observable(observer => {
                         Foo.someFunction(id,
                           {
                            callback: value => {
                                                 observer.next(value);
                                                 observer.complete();
                                               },
                            warningHandler: warn => observer.error(warn),
                            errorHandler: error => observer.error(error)
                          });

                        });
```

It's similar to calling `someFunction` manually but emits to a stream.

Answer (score 0):

From `bindCallback` documentation

> The input is a function func with some parameters, the last parameter
>   must be a callback function that func calls when it is done.

If I understand correctly your code

```
bindCallback(func, mappingFunction)
```

`func` is actually `Foo.someFunction`.

If I look at `Foo.someFunction` this is not a function with a callback function as its last parameter, as it is required by `bindCallback`.

So I am wondering if this code has ever worked.

Comment: Current code works, but only for success callback. This also works `Foo.someFunction(id, function(data) {...});` which is why `bindCallback` works I suppose.